# VBA Copy and Paste after Vlookup is performed

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a more efficient way to copy and paste value after the vlookup code is executed? The idea is that after the vlookup is executed in almost 10,000+ cells I want to copy and paste the values as it makes the excel file more stable.

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim X As Long
Dim Z As Long

'What are the names of our worksheets?
 Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


'Determine last row of source
 With sourceSheet
 SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With outputSheet

 'Determine last row in col C
  OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
 For Y = 17 To 28 'Q to AB
  For X = 2 To OutputLastRow
   If InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Materials") + InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Labor") > 0 And    Cells(2, Y) = "Forecast" Then
 'Apply  formula
 .Cells(X, Y).Formula = _
   "=VLOOKUP($E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$L$" & SourceLastRow & ",Match(" & Cells(1, Y).Address & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$1:$AD$1,0),0)"
   .Cells(X, Y).Select
   .Cells(X, Y).Copy
   .Cells(X, Y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If
 Next
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: To improve the efficiency, why dont you perform the copy/paste operations at the end of for loop. It would be a One time operation then.

Comment: yup correct.  however, I could have VBA execute the vlookup operation and then paste the value to the designated cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With .Cells(X, Y)
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: True.  Thanks.  However, the same can be accomplished with .Cells(X, Y).Value = _
   "=VLOOKUP($E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$L$" & SourceLastRow & ",Match(" & Cells(1, Y).Address & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$1:$AD$1,0),0)"

Comment: Depending on your code, be aware that you may need to use `Application.Evaluate()` (you can also use square brackets [ ] which is shorthand for Application.Evaluate). Alternatively, you can use the actual Vlookup() function built in to VBA

Comment: yup Your right had to put a modifier for VBA to evaluate.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change .Formula to .Value so VBA directly executes the vlookup and then pastes the value

```
  .Cells(X, y).Value = _
  Evaluate("=VLOOKUP($E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$L$" & SourceLastRow & ",Match(" & Cells(1, y).Address & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$1:$AD$1,0),0)")
```